# Inflateexception if I try to load Helpshift fragment

Tags: android, imageview, fragment, inflate-exception, helpshift

I created a Demoapplication with Actionbar. In the NavDrawer, there are 2 Elements, which loads different Fragments. If I try to load. Support.getFAQFragment(...), the following error appears:

```
Process: com.helpshiftdemo.baumar.helpshiftdemo, PID: 20357
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class ImageView
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.setActionView(MenuItemImpl.java:621)
at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.setActionView(MenuItemImpl.java:40)
at android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat.setActionView(MenuItemCompat.java:310)
at android.support.v7.view.SupportMenuInflater$MenuState.setItem(SupportMenuInflater.java:465)
at android.support.v7.view.SupportMenuInflater$MenuState.addItem(SupportMenuInflater.java:479)
at android.support.v7.view.SupportMenuInflater.parseMenu(SupportMenuInflater.java:196)
at android.support.v7.view.SupportMenuInflater.inflate(SupportMenuInflater.java:118)
at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.inflateMenu(Toolbar.java:899)
at com.helpshift.support.fragments.MainFragment.onViewCreated(MainFragment.java:134)
at com.helpshift.support.fragments.SupportFragment.onViewCreated(SupportFragment.java:119)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1086)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 0
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:747)
at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:156)
at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:145)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:57)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:53)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:106)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:963)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1022)
at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:725)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.setActionView(MenuItemImpl.java:621) 
at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.setActionView(MenuItemImpl.java:40) 
at android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat.setActionView(MenuItemCompat.java:310) 
at android.support.v7.view.SupportMenuInflater$MenuState.setItem(SupportMenuInflater.java:465) 
at android.support.v7.view.SupportMenuInflater$MenuState.addItem(SupportMenuInflater.java:479) 
at android.support.v7.view.SupportMenuInflater.parseMenu(SupportMenuInflater.java:196) 
at android.support.v7.view.SupportMenuInflater.inflate(SupportMenuInflater.java:118) 
at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.inflateMenu(Toolbar.java:899) 
at com.helpshift.support.fragments.MainFragment.onViewCreated(MainFragment.java:134) 
at com.helpshift.support.fragments.SupportFragment.onViewCreated(SupportFragment.java:119) 
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1086) 
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252) 
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738) 
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617) 
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517) 
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
```

any idea, why this is happening?

I also added 
**-keep class android.support.v4.** { *; }**
to proguard file.

I dont know how to find any solution.

Code:

```
final HashMap config = new HashMap();
    config.put("toolbarId", R.id.toolbar);
    try {
        mDrawerLayout.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                try {
                    ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, Support.getFAQsFragment(MainActivity.this, config)).commitAllowingStateLoss();
                } catch(IllegalStateException ex) {
                    // activity already destroyed
                }
            }
        }, 300);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
```

Comment: where is your code ?

Comment: i added code obove .. this rows are executed, if i click an item in navdrawer

Comment: you are getting the exception android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class ImageView ,  check your xml file.

Comment: which xml-file? ^^

Answer (score 0):

This occurs mainly if Helpshift fragment doesn't get the required theme elements. Make sure that parent theme for your Activity containing Helpshift Activity is `@style/Helpshift.Theme.Activity`. Make sure that you have followed the steps 4 & 5 [here](https://developers.helpshift.com/android/support-tools/#embeddable-fragments).